# Unable to resolve "Managed Bean" issue while working with Java Serves Faces 2.2

Tags: jsf

[image]

**Template Client.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <body>
        <f:view contracts="#{themeSelector.themeName}">            
            <ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="top">
                <h:form>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Theme" for="menu"></h:outputLabel>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="menu" label="ThemeMenu" value="#{themeSelector.themeName}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dark" itemValue="dark"></f:selectItem>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Normal" itemValue="normal"></f:selectItem>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <h:message for="menu"></h:message>

                <h:commandButton id="Submit" value="Submit" action="templateClient"></h:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>
        </f:view>

    </body>
</html>
```

**ThemeSelector.java**

```
package com.rshingha.example;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;


/**
 *
 * @author rshingha
 */
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class ThemeSelector {
    private String themeName="dark";


    public ThemeSelector()
    {

    }
    public String getThemeName() {

        return themeName;
    }

    public void setThemeName(String themeName) {
        this.themeName = themeName;
    }


}
```

Issue:

Following line in TemplateClient.xhtml

```
<f:view contracts="#{themeSelector.themeName}">
```

Here value of "contracts" attribute is not getting resolved, even when I am doing "Ctrl+click" on property name "themeName",  its not going to that property in bean file

Interesting thing is when I am hardcoding value for "contracts" attribute then its working.

I also tried with **@Named** annotation , but same is happening in that case with one exception:

When I am doing "Ctrl+click" on property name "themeName",  its navigating to that property in bean file

Please suggest anything , I am stuck

Answer (score 1):

You got wrong import for `@ManagedBean`. Use this one `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` from JSF. If you want to use `@Named` (which is CDI technology) then you should also change imports for scopes, request scope would be `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`.

Comment: There are several duplicates of this. Please search for it and mark the question as such